# shouldComponentUpdate is not being invoked

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

shouldComponenUpdate() lifecycle method is not being called. Below is the code snipped form my project.

I have added alert inside shouldComponentUpdate() to see if it is being invoked or not, but the alert message is never triggered. I am using redux for state management.

Someone please help me out of this mess. If any other information is required please let me know.

```
class BusinessDetail extends Component {

    handleSubmit = (values, businessid) => {
        let financialYear = values.fy;
        this.props.addFinancialYear(financialYear, businessid);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if ((this.props.salesDetail.message === '') && (this.props.salesDetail.loading === false)) this.props.getSalesData(this.props.businessid);
        if ((this.props.getCustomer.message === 'initial') && (this.props.getCustomer.loading === false)) this.props.getCustomerList(this.props.businessid);
        if ((this.props.getVendor.message === 'initial') && (this.props.getVendor.loading === false)) this.props.getVendorList(this.props.businessid);
        if ((this.props.getItem.message === 'initial') && (this.props.getItem.loading === false)) this.props.getItemList(this.props.businessid);
        if ((this.props.getBankDetail.message === 'initial') && (this.props.getBankDetail.loading === false)) this.props.getBankDetailList(this.props.businessid);
        if (this.props.addFinancialYearMessage.error !== ''){
            alert("Error : " + this.props.addFinancialYearMessage.error);
            this.props.resetaddFinancialYear();
        }
        if (this.props.addFinancialYearMessage.error === '' && this.props.addFinancialYearMessage.message === "success") {
            alert("FinancialYear Added Successfully");
            this.props.resetaddFinancialYearMessage();
        }
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps,nextState) {
        alert("check");
        if ((this.props.addFinancialYearMessage.error !== '') && (nextProps.addFinancialYearMessage.error === '')) return false;
        else return true; 
    }

    resetCVIB = () => {
        this.props.resetCVIB();
    }

    render() {
        if (!cookie.load('userservice')) return <Redirect to="/" />
        else {
            if ((this.props.getCustomer.error !== '') || (this.props.getVendor.error !== '') || (this.props.getItem.error !== '') || (this.props.getBankDetail.error !== '')) {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <div className="row" style={style.loginHeader}>
                            <div className="container pt-2 pb-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
                                <div className="col-md-10 mt-2 text-white">
.....
```

Class is being called from Route path as below:

```
 <Route exact path="/business/businessdetail/:businessid" component ={BusinessDetailId}/> //this is inside a switch tag with lot other routes.. and definition of BusinessDetailId is provided below..

 const BusinessDetailId = ({match}) => { return <BusinessDetail businessid={match.params.businessid} businessList={this.props.businessList} addFinancialYear={this.props.addFinancialYear} addFinancialYearMessage={this.props.addFinancialYearMessage} resetaddFinancialYearMessage={this.props.resetaddFinancialYearMessage}/> }This contains a lot of others params too.. trimmed for sake of readibility.
```

Comment: can you add the parent component that is rendering this component?

Comment: Did you log/alert in the `render` to verify that its updating at all?

Comment: @BrianThompson yes. In render alert is getting triggered and moreover state UI is also being changed.

Comment: @NiftyAsp

**const BusinessDetailId = ({match}) => {
            return <BusinessDetail businessid={match.params.businessid} businessList={this.props.businessList} addFinancialYear={this.props.addFinancialYear} addFinancialYearMessage={this.props.addFinancialYearMessage} resetaddFinancialYearMessage={this.props.resetaddFinancialYearMessage}/>
        }**_This contains a lot of others params too.. trimmed for sake of readibility._

 <Route exact path="/business/businessdetail/:businessid" component ={BusinessDetailId}/>

Comment: @AnkitBagaria You can update your own question. Add any new code or information to the question itself, not as a comment please. It makes if **very** hard to read.

Comment: @BrianThompson updated the question.

Comment: Figured out the solution. Thankyou everyone.